# Strange behavior of @Binding variable in SwiftUI integrating UIKit (iOS app)

Tags: swift, xcode, data-binding, swiftui, uikit

I am developing an App for my school's courses, displaying the descriptions of the courses as well as a calendar showing the appointments. I decided to use KVKCalendar as a library for the Calendar. Developing with SwiftUI and being the KVKCalendar library a UIKit environment, I had to interface the two systems (with the struct `CalendarRepresentable`, see code).

The app is constructed as follow: I load from the memory an `@ObservedObject` with the saved objects, pass it to some sub-views as `@Binding` in order to save/delete new courses from the course-catalogue.
All changes made in the views are updated accordingly in all the other views, but unfortunately not in the `TimetableView`, connected with the struct `CalendarRepresentable`.

The problem: I want to update the Calendar whenever new courses are saved (e.g. added to the array `courses` of the type `[Courses]`). At the moment the struct `CalendarRepresentable` is calling the `makeUIView` as expected but the calendar is not updated anymore. In particular the saved courses in `courses` are not constantly updated but in a (apparently) inconsitent way: in some functions of the struct `CalendarRepresentable` are indeed up to date, in some other functions (and subclasses) not. See code where I show where and in what case these inconsistencies occure.

Code of the View calling the UIKit-SwiftUI interface:
import SwiftUI
import KVKCalendar

```
struct TimetableView: View {
    @Binding var courses: [Courses]
    let saveAction: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        CalendarRepresentable(courses: $courses)
            
    }
}

struct TimetableView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimetableView(courses: .constant(Courses.data), saveAction: {})
    }
}
```

Code of the interface:

```
import SwiftUI
import KVKCalendar
import EventKit

struct CalendarRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable{
    
    @Binding var courses: [Courses]
    
    var events = [Event]()

 
    var calendar: CalendarView = {
        print("Representable has been launched")
        var style = Style()
        //style of the calendar
        //...       
        return CalendarView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, style: style)
    }()
    
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CalendarView, context: Context ){
        print("updateUIView has been called. Courses has \(courses.count) elements") // **Here courses has always the correct amount of elements**
        
        calendar.dataSource = context.coordinator
        calendar.delegate = context.coordinator
        calendar.reloadData()
        calendar.reloadInputViews()
        print("updateUIView is finished")
    }
    
    public func passCourses() -> [Courses]{
        print("Called passCourses with courses having \(courses.count) elements") //**Here courses has NOT the corrent amount of elements, i.e. after saving/deleting a course courses.count is different from what is printed in the previous function updateUIView**
        return courses
    }
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CalendarView {
        print("makeUIView has been called")
        calendar.dataSource = context.coordinator
        calendar.delegate = context.coordinator
        calendar.reloadData()
        return calendar
    }
    
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        print("makeCoordinator")
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
      
    
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, CalendarDelegate, CalendarDataSource {
        var events = [Event]()
        var parent: CalendarRepresentable
        
        func eventsForCalendar(systemEvents: [EKEvent]) -> [Event] {
            print("eventsForCalendar called. In Coordinator \(events.count) events and \(parent.courses.count) courses") //**here courses are again not uptodate to the CalendarRepresentable' courses**
            loadEvents { (events) in
                self.events = events

            }
            return self.events
        }
        
        

        
        init(_ parent: CalendarRepresentable){
            print("Initialize Coordinator")
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
            
            loadEvents { (events) in
                self.events = events
                self.parent.calendar.reloadData()
            }
        }
        
        func eventsForCalendar() -> [Event] {
            print("eventsForCalendar without parameter")
            return events
        }
        
        
        
        func loadEvents(completion: ([Event]) -> Void) {
            
            var events = [Event]()
        
            print("loadEvents with courses having \(self.parent.courses.count) elements")//**here courses are again not uptodate to the CalendarRepresentable' courses**

            var i: Int=0
            for course in self.parent.passCourses() {

                let isoDateStart = course.startEvent
                let dateStartFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

                let isoDateEnd = course.endEvent
                let dateEndFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
                var event = Event(ID: "\(i)")

                event.start = dateStartFormatter.date(from: isoDateStart)!
                event.end = dateEndFormatter.date(from: isoDateEnd)!
                event.text = course.name

                events.append(event)

                i=i+1
            }
      
            completion(events)
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Example of console output after saving a course (done in another view) with (apparent) inconsistency:

```
Representable has been launched
updateUIView has been called. Courses has 4 elements
eventsForCalendar called. In Coordinator 3 events and 3 courses
loadEvents with courses having 3 elements
Called passCourses with courses having 3 elements
updateUIView is finished
```

Does anyone know what is happening to `courses`? Suggestions on how should I solve the issue?
Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

After extensive testing I found that the problem was that somehow the coordinator had been called with an old parent although the outerstruct had been changed. I am not sure about the internal cause of that behavior, but anyway it should now be solved: the `courses` data is now successfully passed to the coordinator. However, the view still doesn't update itself despite a change in `courses` correctly triggering `updateUIView`. Any advice is appreciated.